# Changing local variable in JavaScript affects original global with different name

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I have a global declared at top of script:

```
var g_nutrition_summary = null;
```

When the user enters the page, I return network data and give this variable a value.

```
g_nutrition_summary = json.data;
```

This line is the ONLY assignment of the variable and is never called again (tested with alerts).

I later use that `json.data` variable to populate a Bar Chart with the plugin `Chart.js`.  The global assignment is for later use.

Underneath the chart, the user can filter certain types of data it displays with a series of checkboxes.  So my goal is, to keep an original value of what comes in from the network, and then make a LOCAL COPY of it and alter the COPY (not the global original) and repopulate the chart.  Everytime the user checks/unchecks a checkbox, it will call this function and grab the ORIGINAL global  (`g_nutrition_summary`) and re-filter that.

Here is how I do it:

```
function filter_nutrition_log()
{
    alert("1: " + JSON.stringify(g_nutrition_summary));

    // reassign object to tmp variable
    var tmp_object = g_nutrition_summary;

    var food_array = new Array("Grains", "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Oils");
    var checked_array = new Array();

    // Make an array of all choices that are checked
    $(".input-range-filter").each(function() 
    {        
        var type = $(this).val(); 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {            
            checked_array.push(type);            
        }     
    });

    alert("2: " + JSON.stringify(g_nutrition_summary));

    // Loop thru all the 7 choices we chart
    $.each(food_array, function(i, val) 
    {
       // find out if choice is in array of selected checkboxes
       if ($.inArray(val, checked_array) === -1)
       {
            // it's not, so delete it from out tmp obj we 
            // will use to repopulate the chart with
            // (we do not want to overwrite the original array!)
            delete tmp_object["datasets"][val];
       }
    });

    // Resert graph
    alert("3: " + JSON.stringify(g_nutrition_summary));
    getNutritionChart(null, tmp_object, null, false);
}
```

Somehow, between alert "1" and alert "2".  The global gets changed.  Then when the user clicks a checkbox again and it calls this function, the very first alert shows that the original, global object contains the altered data to the `tmp_object` variable.

As you can see, I call a third party function I have created when this happens originally.  Doing a search for the global there is absolutely nowhere else it is used in the instances described above.

**Am I not understanding something about JavaScript variable scope?**

Comment: `var tmp_object = g_nutrition_summary;` `tmp_object`  is not a copy, it´s just a reference to `g_nutrition_summary` object. To really make a copy, you need to use `tmp_object = $.extend({}, g_nutrition_summary)`

Comment: @juvian  I had no clue about this.  (obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both objects and arrays in javascript are treated as references, so when trying to pass them to functions or to "copy" them, you are just cloning the reference

To have a "real copy", you would need to traverse the object and copy its content to another object. This can be done recursively, but fortunately jquery already comes with a function that does this: `$.extend`

So the solution would be:

```
var tmp_object = $.extend({},g_nutrition_summary);
```

If you have a nested object, you need to set an extra parameter:

```
var tmp_object = $.extend(true,{},g_nutrition_summary); // now it will do it recursively
```

For arrays, an easy way to make a "real copy" is, as @Branden Keck pointed out,

```
var arrCopy = arrOriginal.slice(0)
```

More on jquery extend: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Comment: I have tried the `extend`  but to the same affect.  No console errors, just the original is being altered.  I am going to verify again.

Comment: @KickingLettuce sorry forgot a parameter, check updated answer. Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/am42gLms/

Comment: Ok, that did it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Going along with juvian's comment.  To create the new array as somewhat of a "copy" and not just a reference, use:

```
var tmp_object= g_nutrition_summary.slice(0);
```

However, .slice() is only works for arrays and will not work on JSON, so to used this method you would have to create an array from the JSON

Another method that I found (although not the cleanest) suggested creating a string from the JSON and re-parsing it:

```
var tmp_object= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(g_nutrition_summary));
```

Comment: When I do this, it says `slice` is not a function?  Keep in mind, the global is an object (if that makes a difference).

Comment: Yeah for arrays this is the correct answer, I think  json.data is an object though as he does `tmp_object["datasets"]`

Comment: @juvian  correct.  There is some data inside the object that is an array that I loop thru in that function above.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Sorry, last time I used JSON, I put it in arrays first before altering, that is why slice worked for me, I will edit my answer to say this and continue to look for a better solution

Comment: Note that with parse + stringify method, if you have an object instead of a json, it will loose it´s functions on the way